# What is the most efficient way for QoS/Bandwith Management?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, qos

I have a Zyxel VMG3312-B10A v2 modem router and I want to isolate my computer from the other peers. Which is the most efficient way in the perspective of power consuming (more power spent means more heat?) and performance (coverage and more bandwidth)?

- Using more than one AP as alternative or guest AP?
- Using the QoS menu (Seems like more advanced but hard to configure
  for me?
- Another way you can suggest?

[image: Zyxel QoS UI]

Comment: Honestly, most consumer routers are not very good at this. But the answer would vary based on your connection (wired or wireless) and the other clients. Generally home routers are not capable of client isolation on the wired interface, and on the wireless side you would need to see if the router has an option for "client isolation" on one or more SSIDs. As far as giving your computer priority over other traffic, you would want your PC to have a static IP and you give that IP address a higher priority. Honestly, power consumption should not be an issue.

Comment: All clients are wireless including me. I can add 3 more different APs at the same time and limit their bandwidth. Using 2 different SSID does effect the performance of router like range? QoS is definetely not working so healthy

Comment: The number of SSID's should not effect range, but can potentially affect throughput if the router doesn't have enough processing power. Adding QoS or bandwidth shaping can also add to processor load. Honestly, if you want to do this effectively, assuming you don't want to invest in enterprise grade equipment, you should look at a quality "gaming" router or perhaps something that is higher end with OpenWRT or DD-WRT compatible

Comment: If your connection feels laggy when multiple people are using it, the solution is usually to fix bufferbloat, not deploy QoS.